# How to read/get Style values of FrameworkElement in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, properties, setter

I need to read values like `Padding` etc. stored in `Style` of `Button` (or other `FrameworkElement`). How to do this?

For example if I make a `Style` for `Button` like this:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Button));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.HeightProperty, 70));
MyButton.Style = style;
```

So... How I can read later for example the `Setter HeightProperty`? And what about in case below? How to get `Padding`?

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                    Padding="11,15,7,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I have tried to get information by

```
Style ButtonStyle = MyButton.GetStyle();
```

but after this I don't get it at all how to continue.

Comment: Are you aware that you can use styles as resources and reuse them like that? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles

Comment: Have a look at `Style` property of FrameworkElement [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.style) You can use a `Setters` collection of retrieved object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you can get the currently applied value using the `GetValue` mehtod:

```
var value = (double)MyButton.GetValue(Button.HeightProperty);
```

Or even more simply:

```
var value = MyButton.Height;
```

In second case the problem is a bit more complicated, as the `Padding` is part of the template itself, not the button. To access it, you will need the following helper method:

```
public IEnumerable<TChildType> FindChildren<TChildType>(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is TChildType typedChild)
        {
            yield return typedChild;
        }

        foreach (var nestedChild in FindChildren<TChildType>(child))
        {
            yield return nestedChild;
        }
    }
}
```

This traverses the `VisualTree` under a parent and searches for descendants of certain type. We can use it like this:

```
var contentPresenter = FindChildren<ContentPresenter>(MyButton).First();
Debug.WriteLine(contentPresenter.Padding);
```

Make sure to call the `FindChildren` method only after the page is actually loaded (for example in the `Page.Loaded` event handler, or `OnNavigatedTo`), as in the `Page` constructor, the template children do not exist yet and the helper would return no children.

Comment: Great!!! 100% working solution. Type "TChildType" was unknown me before. You really make my day!

Comment: It is not an actual type per se, actually it is a placeholder for any type provided (this is the C# generics). It is then replaced by the actual type you pass in - so in this case `ContentPresenter`